# R: evaluate object name before being removed

Tags: r, variables

I would like to remove an object, the name of which is contained in a string object.

```
a <- 1
b <- "a"
```

I tried to do:

```
> rm(get(b))
Error in rm(get(b)) : ... must contain names or character strings
> remove(eval(b))
Error in remove(eval(b)) : ... must contain names or character strings
```

How can I get R to remove the object whose name is contained as a string in `b` (namely, here, `a`)?

Answer (score 5):

Just

```
rm(list = b)
```

From `?rm`:

> list: a character vector naming objects to be removed.

In order to reach your desired output you can do

```
rm(list = eval(b))
```

Or (as proposed by @James)

```
eval(call("rm", b))
```

Comment: Gah, that's what the documentation meant! (facepalm)

Comment: The `eval` issue is due to non-standard evaluation of `...` I think. `eval(call("rm",b))` does the trick.

Comment: You just need to RM ;)